# XDSoft DateTimePicker -- Disable manual edit

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-plugins

I'm using the [xdsoft datetimepicker](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) jQuery plugin.  It correctly prevents erroneous and manual entry, however; after a date has been selected and the input element is populated with a value -- you can edit the value.  My question is, does anyone know of a way to prevent this behavior without the use of the `readonly` attribute as that prevents the datetimepicker from working altogether?

I have already tried the `readonly` attribute as well as binding to keypress events and `.preventDefault()` -- neither have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I figured out the issue.  The [API](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#onChangeDateTime) actually supports an `onChangeDateTime` function callback.  You can handle this and when the input element loses focus you can ensure that the date is correct if the `mindate` attribute is supposed to be today.

I have the following in my angular directive:

```
            var ensureDate = (dp, input) => {
                var attr = element.attr("mindate");
                if (attr && attr == '0') {
                    var date = new Date();
                    date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    var now = moment(date);
                    var val = moment(Date.parse(input.val()));

                    if (val.isBefore(now)) {
                        element.val(now.format("M/D/YYYY HH:mm"));
                    }
                }
            }

            if (type) {
                element.datetimepicker({
                    format: 'm/d/Y H:i',
                    formatDate: 'm/d/Y',
                    minDate: attributes.mindate,
                    maxDate: attributes.maxdate,
                    mask: '23:00',
                    defaultTime: '00:00',
                    id: attributes.id + '-picker',
                    onChangeDateTime: ensureDate
                });
            } else {
                element.datetimepicker({
                    timepicker: false,
                    format: 'm/d/Y',
                    formatDate: 'm/d/Y',
                    minDate: attributes.mindate,
                    maxDate: attributes.maxdate,
                    closeOnDateSelect: true,
                    id: attributes.id + '-picker',
                    onChangeDateTime: ensureDate
                });
            }
```